# Erro ao criar novo projeto Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, instalador

Estou tentando criar meu primeiro projeto Laravel, estou usando Ubuntu 16.04 LTS e ao tentar criar meu novo projeto ele mostra o seguinte erro:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel app "5.2.*"
>   The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Success
>   failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
>   https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The "http://packagist.org/p/laravel/laravel%244c31ada56dbaa88845a0029f2c88a
>     c382a881cebea2322290bbbb914e252d6ed.json" file could not be downloaded (HTT
>     P/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required)
>
> create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

Ja tentei procurar qual é o problema com o JSON mas não achei nada a respeito.

Tenho o Laravel Installer 2.0.1.

Gostaria de criar um projeto com Laravel 5.4
`

Comment: O erro  se  refere a erro de rede, possui proxy na dere ? geralmente pode ser um bloqueio ao site de download

Comment: possui proxy sim, mas como faço para permitir esse download?

Comment: vai ter que entrar na configuração de seu  rotador (router/moden) e liberar acesso a packegist.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa liberar no proxy o "https://packagist.org/packages.json"
Se for no modem você entra nele e coloca a url base nos permitidos, agora se o proxy for em um servidor ou você precisa pedir liberação do adm ou liberar você mesmo se tiver acesso.
No mais é só liberar o https://packagist.org que ele já vai te dar acesso e conseguir fazer a instalação.